# array of objects passed as props not updating child component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a general Vue question I can't figure out.  I have 3 components, a parent ( selection widget ), a child ( checkbox list ), and multiple grandchildren ( checkboxes ).  The parent has an array of checkbox objects, each with an `id`, `label`, and `checked` property.  The array is passed into the child component through `props`.  The child component loops over the array, binding `id`, `label`, and `checked` to `props` of each `checkbox` component.  When the checkbox is clicked, the grandchild ( checkbox ) emits an event with the `id` and whether the checkbox is checked.  The child ( checkbox list ) emits the same event to pass it up the chain to the parent ( selection widget ).  The parent finds the corresponding checkbox object in the checkboxes array and changes the value of `checked`.

This is all working correctly, however, the checkbox never checks, so the data passed from the parent through the child, and into the grandchildren components isn't registering the change.  If I attempt to check a few checkboxes, nothing happens, although, when I cause the checkbox list to rerender, those checkboxes are checked.  Can anyone help me figure out what I'm missing?

my code for updating the checkbox in the parent component:

```
onChange: function( selection ) {

    var targetCheckbox = this.checkboxes.find( function( checkbox ) {
        return checkbox.id === selection.id;
    });

    var targetCheckboxIndex = this.checkboxes.indexOf( targetCheckbox );

    var updatedCheckbox = Object.assign( {}, targetCheckbox, selection );

    this.$set( this.checkboxes, targetCheckboxIndex, updatedCheckbox );
}
```

where selection may look like:

`{ id: "12", checked: true }`

and the checkboxes array may look like:

```
[
    { label: 'Business Operations', id: '1', checked: false },
    { label: 'Business Ventures', id: '2', checked: false },
    { label: 'Customer-Centric Strategies', id: '3', checked: false }
]
```

Comment: Seeing some code would greatly help us help you.

Comment: adding it to the original question now.  It's late and my head wasn't on straight when I posted.

Comment: Did you console what `this.checkboxes` prints